# What about being not particularly considered out sometimes?

Tags: riddle, word

I'm here and I want to reiterate a few things:

Clue 1:

> I can be composed by one or more elements

Clue 2:

> I'm important, but usually people is focused on other elements...

Clue 3:

> But there are times when I'm the protagonist

Clue 4:

> It's not rare to be modified by some softwares... am I wrong?

Clue 5:

> My name is about hands fingers

**Who am I?**

**Edit:** Some hints to help you finding the answer!

Hint 1:

> I'm composed by the union of two words

Hint 2:

> Near distance or far distance... I don't care, I'm always there

Comment: the riddle is the clues? where is it?

Comment: The clues make the riddle, check my profile to understand better

Comment: @xKobalt is the answer rot 13(Eryngvbafuvc)??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really know what is it...

Comment: Do you mean that you do not know to read in rot 13 or not knowing answer?? If it's the first one you can easily decode it by searching for online rot 13 decryption?? @xKobalt

Comment: Encryption does not matter for this riddle, I know the answer

Answer (score 2):

Another one from my side

> Fire

I can be composed by one or more elements

> Fire needs air and fuel to be able to sustain.

I'm important but usually people is focused on other elements

> Fire is one of the important five elements of life but usually ignored.

But there are times when I am protagonist.

> Fire is considered to be divine entity in Hindu mythology and is an integral part of many rituals.

It's not rare to be modified by some softwares...am I wrong??

> Maybe referring to firewall.

My name is about hands fingers.

> Rings of fire probably. I feel like it's a bit stretched.

Comment: This answer is well explained and focused on the details, it's very accurate, but unfortunately neither this is the object I thought

Comment: I felt like this would not be intended as I have not explained last one properly. Great puzzle and +1. Would you mind posting some hint @xKobalt??

Comment: I've added them, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> index?

I can be composed by one or more elements

> An index is a list

I'm important, but usually people is focused on other elements.../

But there are times when I'm the protagonist

> Say the index is a bibliography of a book. People usually use it to locate sources, but it can be relevant too if you want to know what to consult for a certain topic.

It's not rare to be modified by some softwares... am I wrong?/

My name is about hands fingers

> Indices I suppose are a common feature in software. Index finger is the most nimble of five fingers.

Comment: The replies provided seem to feet close as the solution, with a good explanation and a consistent commitment, but unfortunately is not the answer I thought about despite it's a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Digit?

I can be composed by one or more elements

> Digits form a number together

I'm important, but usually people is focused on other elements...

> People look at the whole number or the significant digits

But there are times when I'm the protagonist

> Significant digits, also I'm "number one"

It's not rare to be modified by some softwares... am I wrong?

> All software basically just modify numbers, also this is considered "digital"

My name is about hands fingers

> A digit also means finger

I'm composed by the union of two words

> "dig" "it"

Near distance or far distance... I don't care, I'm always there

> Digital signals don't lose info over distances, in contrast to analog

Comment: This should be a valid answer, if it weren't for Clue #2 and Clue #3. **Clue #2**: `Digits form a number together` explains Digits compose, but not Digit is composed by... I could accept, instead, the reference of Binary Digit, where every Digit is composed by bits. **Clue #3:** `People look at the whole number or the significant digits` explains the digits are the main object, but in the clue there's written that people is focused on other elements, while I could accept, instead, that in a book there are page numbers, but always people is focused on the page content.